# facing problems in uploading files to a particular directory

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

i am using a html template to upload a file but i don't know how to process that file in django views file
i also have a model which is connected with the database

here is my html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<form action="file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="username">
   <input name="file" type="file">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
{% for message in messages %}
  {{ message }}

  {%endfor%}
{% endblock %}
```

and here is my views.py function

```
def File(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = request.POST['userName']
            file = request.FILES
            print(file)
            # file = request.POST.copy()
            # file.update(request.FILES)
            # content_type = copied_data['file'].get('content-type')
            # path = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\harsh\PycharmProjects\swatchBharat\SwatchBharat\media\files\\',file)
            if User.objects.filter(username=user).exists():
                file2 = points()
                file_obj1 = DjangoFile(open(file, mode='rb'), name=file)
                file_obj = File.objects.create(title=file, file=file_obj1, content_object=file, author=file.client)
                file2.file =file2.save(ContentFile(file_obj))
                file2.user = user
                file2.save()
                return HttpResponse('sucess bale bale!!!!!!!')
            else:
                messages.info(request,'the username you entered is incorrect')
                return redirect("file")
        return render(request, 'file.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('sorry this is restricted, login to continue')
```

my model.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class points(models.Model):
     user = models.TextField(max_length=50,default=None)
     file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
     point_3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     point_5 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     point_9 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

i am stuck with it pls someone help me out

Comment: You can do through this documentation. Might be helpful. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? You didn't answer a question. Jus stating "I'm stuck" doesn't help. PLease be more specific. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: i am stuck means i tried with many of the solution on stackoverflow but it didn't work you can see it in code as comments

Comment: and the files in am getting in input from form is image and video

Comment: and i want to add them to my model object file field which should be uploaded to my destination directory and to database but its come out as error 'file' object has no attribute '_committed' and sometimes the error that it needs bytes type input but i am giving multidic data

Answer (score 0):

the solution for this is simple , thanks to shivendra-pratap-kushwaha for documentation link -  docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads this was really helpfull
just need to specify request.FILES['file'] instead of request.FILES